# Calling method from inheriting class when async logic completes in BaseClass

Tags: angular, typescript

I am developing an Angular app. I have a class which extends a baseclass. It's probably an antipattern but what would be a recommended way for BaseClass to call methodB() in MyClass after BaseClass has completed running async call?

```
     export class MyClass extends BaseClass {
          constructor() {
             super();
          }

          methodA() {
            bcMethod();
          }

          methodB() {
          }
        }

    export class BaseClass  {      
       constructor () {}

          bcMethod() {
// Do some async stuff
              // call methodB in MyClass
              // or notify MyClass in someway that bcMethod has finished
          }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make abstract method in base class and then you need to implement that method in your extended class then you can call that abstract method from base class. It will trigger method in extended class

Answer (score 0):

Since your class inherits from base class, you can call method b just by using methodB() from the child class